# Qt - How to apply a QToolTip on rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to inform user when cursor hover on the particular rectangle. I have many 20x20 rectangles. Below you can see how I draw the rectangles.

```
            QRect rec(horizontalScan,verticalScan,20,20);
            QPen framepen(Qt::black);
            framepen.setWidth(1);

            QBrush brush(colors[randColorNo],Qt::SolidPattern);
            painter.fillRect(rec,brush);
            painter.setPen(framepen);
            painter.drawRect(rec);
```

Please consider that I am not so good on Qt so try to explain exactly what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want interactivity - better use QGraphicsScene. QGraphicsItems has tooltip attribute.

If you want to stick with QPainter - you should do it manually by detecting mouse position with [mouseMoveEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) and showing tooltip with [QToolTip::showText()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText).